# Giving elements new id

Tags: javascript, input, addition

I want to add ids to inputs dynamicly using javascript.How can I do that.I wrote a function but it wouldn't work.

html

```
<form>
element 0_0 <input type = "text" class = "elements"></input>
element 0_1 <input type = "text" class = "elements"></input>
element 1_0 <input type = "text" class = "elements"></input>
element 1_1 <input type = "text" class = "elements"></input>
<input type = "button" onclick = "giveId('elements')"></input>
</form>
```

javascript

```
function giveId(className){
var array = document.getElementsByClassName(className)
for(var i = 0;i < array.length; i++){
    array[i].id = "A" + i;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inputs are self closing:

```
<form>
    element 0_0 <input type="text" class="elements" />
    element 0_1 <input type="text" class="elements" />
    element 1_0 <input type="text" class="elements" />
    element 1_1 <input type="text" class="elements" />
    <input type="button" onclick="giveId('elements')" />
</form>
```

and className is an element propery in javascript, so you should use a different name:

```
function giveId(cName) {
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName(cName)
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].id = "A" + i;
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mjZda/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine.
Have you tried selecting your new IDs?

```
<form>
element 0_0 <input type = "text" class = "elements"></input>
element 0_1 <input type = "text" class = "elements"></input>
element 1_0 <input type = "text" class = "elements"></input>
element 1_1 <input type = "text" class = "elements"></input>
<input type = "button" onclick = "giveId('elements')"></input>
</form>

<script>
function giveId(classname){
    var array = document.getElementsByClassName(classname)
    for(var i = 0;i < array.length; i++){
        array[i].id = "A" + i;
    }
}
</script>
```